# Nano editor ( linux ) - specify color from command line

Tags: linux, nano

Is it possible to specify color scheme that is used by `nano` from command line?

For example, say you want the file `sample.test` to be colored using the `php` color scheme, what command should be used?

Comment: So do you want to switch color schemes (like PHP function names are pink and you'd rather them be purple) or try to force it to detect a file as being PHP when it currently is not doing so?

Comment: @rockymcg: that doesn't really answers the question. The question asks how to force a specific color scheme I think... If it can't for instance be derived from the mimetype or the extension.

Answer (score 1):

From the manual of `nano` (`man nano`):

> ```
> -Y str (--syntax=str)
>               Specify a specific syntax highlighting from the nanorc to use, if available.
> ```

So you can use the `-Y` option and then use for instance php:

```
nano -Y php file.test
```

Note that the syntax must be registered in the `nanorc` file. Check [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/90013/how-do-i-enable-syntax-highlighting-in-nano) for more details on how to install and register color schemes.

You can find the name of a color scheme by reading the `.nanorc` files:

```
$ head /usr/share/nano/java.nanorc 
## Here is an example for Java.
##
syntax "java" "\.java$"
```

So the name for the java highlighting is `java`.

Comment: Yes, you right. And thank you.
Except this one worked for me
nano --syntax=php file.test
did not get -Y option to work.